# WP7 Application deployment for presentation

Tags: windows-phone-7

How could I go about presenting a Windows Phone 7 application with a laptop?

Do I need to install Visual Studio on the laptop with which I will be making the presentation? I've read somewhere about a stand-alone emulator but I haven't found any info on how to load the app to the emulator (total MS-anything newbie here).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If demonstrating via the emulator you'll need to install the tools including VS.

Comment: Hi Mick, thanks a lot for your answer. I was kinda afraid of that, since I have limited access to the presentation machine. If I manage to get a phone, could you please give me a few pointers about deploying to the phone without using the tools? Thanks again.

Comment: yw :) Deploying to the phone is done using the XAP Deployment tool, which.. you guessed it... is installed with the tools ;) You could have a look at the iso install and see if it's possible to selectively do some of the install components that are broken down more on that.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you have an actual device.*

Using an actual phone and a webcam can help give people a better idea about what the app will look like.
If you're showing it to people unfamiliar with the phone then the fact that the UI is so different to what they may have seen on phones before is likley to be a distraction. If you have a real phone then you can better demonstrate your app in context and in comparison with the other apps on the phone.

Tip. Try and use a HD camera if possible as this will make it easier to see the details on the screen.